# How can I use Let's Encrypt (letsencrypt.org) as a free SSL certificate provider?

Tags: debian, ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

I have a few sites running with a StartSSL free certificate ([CJSHayward.com](https://cjshayward.com), [JobhuntTracker.com](https://jobhunttracker.com)), and Firefox rejects StartSSL and displays an error page saying that my server is not properly configured (IIRC) because of the certificate chain. I asked for help and confirmed that my VirtualHost (available on request) was for the certificate chain and I had the intermediate certificate installed correctly. The sites are displayed without errors that I am aware of in Chrome, Safari, Edge, or Opera.

After some searching, [Let's Encrypt!](https://www.letsencrypt.org) looked like an attractive offering, and before too long I had (AFAICT) a private key and a certificate for each domain under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, minus of course any domains that are no longer mine. I thought I'd do a trial run and make an HTTPS connection to a site now available only under HTTP: [JSH.name](http://JSH.name). I moved the "Let's Encrypt!" certificate and private key to my SSL directory and added:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin cjshayward@pobox.com
        DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/stornge
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/0000_csr-letsencrypt.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/0000_key-letsencrypt.pem
        ServerName jsh.name
        ServerAlias www.jsh.name
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /home/jonathan/logs/stornge.com combined
        <Directory /home/jonathan/stornge/>
            Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I rebooted to see my work, and every HTTP or HTTPS request I made simply hung. This included two domains on HTTPS with my StartSSL certificate, and the domain that should have been newly available on HTTPS accessed via both HTTP and HTTPS. I commented out the VirtualHost and bounced Apache, and all of the old functionality was back again in working order.

Have I used Let's "Encrypt!" correctly? I'm slightly suspicious as existing SSL configuration has private keys with an extension of .key, a certificate extension of .crt, and a certificate chain file with extension .pem.

I tried again after checking the SSL directory and finding that 0000_csr.letsencrypt.pem was mode 644; I changed all files in that directory to mode 600. When I tried a moment ago, I got a repeat of the old behavior: the website hangs on all requests and, in addition, an `apachectl restart` gets a statement (I forget the exact wording) that httpd is not running and the computer is trying to start it.

How can I get working free certitificates for "Let's Encrypt" or some other tool that hasn't alienated Firefox?

An `apachectl -v` gives:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
```

A `uname -a` gives:

```
Linux www 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 #2 SMP Tue Jan 19 12:43:53 EST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**--UPDATE--**

Contents deleted, 0000_key-letsencrypt.pem is bounded by:

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`
`-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

A find on the directory heirarchy yields:

```
root@www:/etc/letsencrypt# find `pwd` -print
/etc/letsencrypt
/etc/letsencrypt/keys
/etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-letsencrypt.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/1ef8dc9b994b9b68a4e9c7cedd003be3
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/1ef8dc9b994b9b68a4e9c7cedd003be3/private_key.json
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/1ef8dc9b994b9b68a4e9c7cedd003be3/meta.json
/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/1ef8dc9b994b9b68a4e9c7cedd003be3/regr.json
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal
/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
/etc/letsencrypt/csr
/etc/letsencrypt/csr/0000_csr-letsencrypt.pem
```

The directory /home/jonathan/stornge and its contents are world readable and world executable where that would make a difference.

--UPDATE--

Adding something substantive here:

The http://OrthodoxChurchFathers.com Apache conf file has two VirtualHosts, one to serve up http://OrthodoxChurchFathers.com and one to redirect http://www.OrthodoxChurchFathers.com requests to http://OrthodoxChurchFathers.com. The .conf file housing both VirtualHosts is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName orthodoxchurchfathers.com
    #ServerAlias www.orthodoxchurchfathers.com fathers.jonathanscorner.com
```

```
DocumentRoot /home/cjsh/fathers/document_root
&lt;Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
&lt;/Directory>
&lt;Directory /home/cjsh/fathers>
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
&lt;/Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
&lt;Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
&lt;/Directory>
```

</VirtualHost>

```
&lt;VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin CJSHayward@POBox.com
ServerName www.orthodoxchurchfathers.com
ServerAlias fathers.jonathanscorner.com
DocumentRoot /home/cjsh/oldmirror
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://orthodoxchurchfathers.com$1 [R=301,L]
&lt;/VirtualHost></pre></code>
```

When I try to run it and request orthodoxchurchfathers.com alone, I get:

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │ We were unable to find a vhost with a ServerName or Address of       │  
   │ orthodoxchurchfathers.com.                                           │  
   │ Which virtual host would you like to choose?                         │  
   │ (note: conf files with multiple vhosts are not yet supported)        │  
   │ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
   │ │1   008-stornge.conf               | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │2   014-paraskeva.conf             | paraskeva.jonathansco |      │ │  
   │ │3   036-unixytalk.conf             | unixtalk.jsh.name     |      │ │  
   │ │4   038-proxy.conf                 | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │5   027-anna.conf                  | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │6   044-jobhunt-tracker.creation.c | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │7   049-jsh.conf                   | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │8   001-steampunk.conf             |                       |      │ │  
   │ │9   006-blajeny.conf               | Multiple Names        |      │ │  
   │ │10  032-videos.conf                | Multiple Names        |     d│ │  
   │ └────↓(+)──────────────────────────────────────────────────30%─────┘ │  
   ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤  
   │                                     │  
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

The command I used was with ./letsencrypt-auto --debug certonly.

Comment: The filename `0000_csr-letsencrypt.pem` suggests you included the certificate signing request, not the actual signed certificate. Every file you need should be in a subdirectory of `/etc/letsencrypt/live` with your domain name. and a serial number, you don't need anything from `/etc/letsencrypt/csr`  or `keys`  Do you have log file entries?

Comment: does apache have rights to read `/home/jonathan/stornge`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a pair of how-tos for running Let's Encrypt SSL certs on CentOS: [initial setup](https://antipaucity.com/2016/01/06/lets-encrypt-centos-6-truly-free-ssl) & [cronning it](https://antipaucity.com/2016/02/26/automated-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-renewal-on-centos-7).

And my per-domain (I use the file naming convention of `z-<[sub-]domain-tld>.conf`) Apache config files look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
Redirect permanent / https://domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerName domain.tld
    ErrorLog logs/domain-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain-access_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    ServerAdmin user@domain.tld

    SSLEngine on

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    <Directory "/var/www/domain">
         Options All +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And my ssl.conf looks like this:

```
#SSL options for all sites
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex sysvsem default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  1024
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
SSLCompression          off
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Using Let's Encrypt to get SSL certs (and get your site up to an "A" rating from [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)) is pretty straight-forward - once you get past some of the arcana of the Apache configs and LE command-line arguments.

Comment: Thank you; may I suggest a revision to your HOWTO? Let's Encrypt doesn't  do multiple VirtualHosts in one .conf file; you might add a step before Let's Encrypt looks through the .conf files that any domain or subdomain served by Let's Encrypt should have only its VirtualHost in the .conf file, and files with multiple VirtualHosts should be separated so that Let's Encrypt finds one VirtualHost, one .conf file for every domain where you address encryption. (This includes a file that has a real site at domain.tld and with it a VirtualHost redirecting www.domain.tld to the real location.)

Comment: @JonathanHayward - I run Let's Encrypt in `--standalone certonly` mode (see my [cronning how-to](https://antipaucity.com/2016/02/26/automated-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-renewal-on-centos-7/) (`~/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --agree-tos --keep --rsa-key-size 2048 --standalone certonly -m user@domain.tld -d domain.tld [-d sub.domain.tld [-d ...]]`)), I don't use any of the plugins (like automatically scanning Apache configs), which I cover in both how-tos. I appreciate the suggestion, but am having good success in `standalone` mode and letting it update certs behind the scenes, so to speak.

Comment: Ok, but I was writing out of difficulties with ``standalone`` ``certonly``. I didn't use automatic scanning.

Comment: @JonathanHayward - what issues have you had with `--standalone certonly`?

Comment: Thank you; see the updated question. I've also posted a question at http://serverfault.com/questions/768643/why-is-lets-encrypt-now-failing-to-look-up-an-a-record-from-pragmatometer-com , which is related but separate and I did not want to tack it on to an already verbose question.

Answer (score 1):

I had good success using EFF's [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) in web root mode (because the idea of an automated process stopping the web server, even if only briefly, during certificate renewal scares me).

First, install Certbot. If you are on Debian Jessie (which is current at the time of my writing this), first add the `jessie-backports` repository, then

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
```

This will bring in a handful of packages plus certbot itself.

Then, to create a certificate in [webroot](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) mode, run something like

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /srv/www/www.example.net/htdocs -d www.example.net
```

You can optionally add `--register-unsafely-without-email` as well as `--rsa-key-size X` if you want a modulus size other than the default (which is currently 2048 bits). `-d fqdn.example.com` can be repeated an arbitrary number of times, as can `-w`; each `-w` starts a new set of domains served out of a directory, domains named by `-d`. Let's Encrypt does not issue wildcard certificates (this is mentioned in their FAQ) and apparently, also not certificates for Punycode domain names.

The user that `certbot` runs as needs, at the very least and by default, write access to several places under `/etc/letsencrypt`. It's probably easiest to just run it as root. It will create a file under `.well-known/acme-challenge` under the given web root directory (`-w`), have the remote system [verify that it's accessible](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-acme-acme-04#section-7.2) over the specified domain names *over HTTP*, and if everything checks out will create a bunch of PEM files in `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.example.net` plus a corresponding set of symbolic links in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net` and print a friendly success message.

If everything checks out, what's left for you to do is to set up your web server to use the certificate found in the host name subdirectory of `/etc/letsencrypt/live` for HTTPS for the domain in question. The absolute bare minimum for this for Apache is something similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.net
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Add any other directives as desired, verify using `apache2ctl -S` and `apache2ctl configtest` that everything checks out, and activate the HTTPS virtual host with `apache2ctl graceful`.

Don't forget to renew the certificate regularly; currently, Let's Encrypt certificates expire after 90 days. The Debian package ships with a cron job in `/etc/cron.d/certbot` and a systemd service in `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service` which take care of this, or you can run `certbot renew` manually. Remember to `apache2ctl graceful` to start using the newly issued certificate; you may want to adjust the cron job or systemd service to do this automatically. To automatically load renewed certificates into Apache on Debian Jessie, consider updating `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service` to add to the `[Service]` section (note: the order is important):

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/apache2ctl configtest
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/apache2ctl graceful
```

Doing so will automatically load the renewed certificate *if* the Apache configuration files pass `configtest`, and list Certbot as a failed unit if the `configtest` or `graceful` fails.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the client [ACME](https://github.com/hlandau/acme) works well, it's easy to set up and get going, it's updated regularly and is easy to update, and it works very well on Amazon Linux. I've written a tutorial on it which you can find [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/).

Get started by downloading ACME and setting it up

```
https://github.com/hlandau/acme.git
cp ./acmetool /usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/acmetool quickstart
```

Request a certificate

```
./acmetool want example.com www.example.com
```

This is how I set up the directory for the challenge - this is where Let's Encrypt connects to your server to validate

```
mkdir -p /var/www/acme-challenge/.well-known/acme-challenge
chmod -R user:www-data /var/www/acme-challenge/*
find /var/www/acme-challenge/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
vi /var/www/acme-challenge/.well-known/acme-challenge/text.html   (add "hello world!" or similar)
```

There's more detail and commentary on the linked website above, and the author and community are helpful.